# Yii2 UrlManager route a file name

Tags: regex, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have the following rule in my UrlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'cache' => null,
            'rules' => [
                'classic_articles/<route:.*>' => 'site/classic-articles',

                // your rules go here
            ]
        ],
```

However it is not going to the new path when route is a file name

```
i.e blank%20document.pdf
```

It does work when there is no .pdf on the end.

Comment: This is probably because your server is trying to serve uri's ending with .pdf differently and not routing it to Yii's index.php. Check to verify that your request is actually routed to your Yii app

Comment: @Amitm Usual PDFs load normally though? Just not the routing.